What is the mathematical shape of the liquid surface near a needle due to surface tension
I am trying to understand the exact shape of a liquid surface when a needle floats on it due to surface tension. I know that the surface curves around the needle, forming either a concave or convex shape depending on the forces involved.
What kind of mathematical function describes the curve of this surface? For example, is it exponential, parabolic, or something else?
How would I derive the equation for this curve, and what parameters would it depend on?
I'm specifically interested in understanding the equation that governs this shape, considering factors like surface tension, density of the liquid, and gravity. Thank you!
